# How to convert SQL Server Query into Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working in Access 2010 and am stuck with a poor table design.

The table has multiple columns that may contain a name I need to find.

ie
 Company, Company DBA1,Company DBA2,DBA3,DBA4,DBA5 etc... Company DBA12

The best that I have come up with is: (assuming I am looking for jbl)

```
      Select Company ,ClientNumber  
      From tblClient 
      Where Company = 'jbl' or DBA1='jbl' or DBA2='jbl'... DBA12='jbl'
```

While it works it is horribly slow!!!

I have found that if I were able to use SQLServer (which I cannot)  I could use a Stored Procedure like this:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @Sql    varchar(max)

    set @sql = 

                'select  Company ,ClientNumber 
                 from dbo.tblClient
                 where isnull([Company],'''') + isnull( [Company DBA],'''') + isnull( [Company DBA2],'''') + isnull( [Company DBA3],'''') + isnull( [Company DBA4],'''') + isnull( [Company DBA5],'''') + isnull( [Company DBA6],'''') + isnull( [Company DBA7],'''') + isnull( [Company DBA8],'''') + isnull( [Company DBA9],'''') + isnull( [Company DBA10],'''') + isnull( [Company DBA11],'''') + isnull( [Company DBA12],'''') like ''%'+@Look4+'%'' 
     order by company'

     print @sql
     exec (@sql)
END
```

This is quite fast.

So I am wondering if there is away to create a similar query or Stored procedure in MS Access 2010?

Comment: I personally love the flexibilty of Dynamic SQL like you showed in your example.... is doing a VBA proc in Access an option. I have never actually written on but I understand it is the alternative. W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct translation into Access would be:

```
select * from tblClient
where company & dba1 & dba2 & dba3 like '*jbl*'
```

EDIT:
To make an exact match, you could do:

```
select * from tblClient
where '|' & company & '|' & dba1 & '|' & dba2 & '|' & dba3 & '|' like '*|' & 'jbl' & '|*'
```

Comment: if the & operator is really saying `AND` than that would be incorrect. And technically the OP said `Company = 'jbl'`... why force him to use a `LIKE`

Comment: In Access SQL, "&" is the concatenation operator.  So this is just building a string.

And I don't think Text columns can be `NULL`, so if you're looking for "jbl" then
    `'TimeWarnerCablejblTWC' like '*jbl*'`
will work.

Comment: What if the company is called, say, 'OR', you will have multiple false matches.

Comment: Indeed if you're searching for something generic you'll have problems, but that's a risk the OP took with his SQL Server code so I figured OP would be fine with that in the Access version.

Comment: It appears that this just might be the best solution!  It is extremely quick compared to my previous query.

Comment: Well then, feel free to accept this as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using a union query to at least make the table look normal:

```
  SELECT q.Company, q.ClientNumber, q.DBA 
  FROM 
  (SELECT Company, ClientNumber, DBA1 As DBA FROM tblClient 
  UNION All
   SELECT Company, ClientNumber, DBA2 As DBA FROM tblClient 
  ....) As q
  Where q.Company = "jbl" or q.DBA="jbl"
```

You can, of course, save the normalized version as a query and then use that 'view' in other queries, which would give you:

```
  PARAMETERS SearchString Text;
  SELECT Company, ClientNumber, DBA 
  FROM ANormalTable
  WHERE Company = SearchString Or DBA = SearchString
```

Note that once you add WHERE that does not specifically include null, all nulls are ignored.

Reference: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/combine-the-results-of-several-select-queries-by-using-a-union-query-HA010206109.aspx

Comment: Ill see if I can give that a try, do you think it will run faster?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last part??  I'm not that Access Savvy!  How to make it a view

Comment: No, I do not think it will run faster. To make a 'view' just save a union query and then use it it future queries.